# I can't pick stuff up in PocketMine Realms

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can play on PocketMine Realms just fine, jumping, hitting people, chatting, etc. Whenever I try to pick up any items, the app crashes. I can pick up stuff in singleplayers and on LAN servers.

I am using Minecraft PE full, BlockLauncher Pro, and no mods with BlockLauncher, just the PocketMine Realms redirection. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Sounds like there are a bunch of crash bugs in the latest version of BlockLauncher.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.pro) You may just need to wait for an update.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Okay. I hope I can still do PocketMine Realms without BlockLauncher Pro.

Comment: This has been patched today with an update of BlockLauncher Pro.

Comment: So it works now? If so, make that an answer and accept it once the self-answer delay is past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is no longer a problem, as the author of BlockLauncher Pro has released an update today fixing the fatal error. Happy Minecrafting!